# How to add a new row underneath the current one on request

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, row

I am trying to build a form in Google Sheets. I have one row which is a drop down list (cell A10, data validation-list from range). The whole sheet is only columns A and B, as the others I have deleted.  I need to give a way for anyone editing the file to add a copy of that cell underneath it, and keep the drop down list, so they can choose more than one option from that list if needed.

Best I can figure, this should be doable with check boxes and some scripting, but I am just now learning scripting, so I have no idea how the script should look.

I need a way to do this automatically (as in, inserting a new row with the same drop down list when they check a box, or anything else similar) as some of the people that will be filling out this form are **really** not technical at all, so just telling them to copy the row will not work.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You have a simple question with a more complex explanation.  Not sure what you want. Please add images, tables and code.

Comment: In my opinion, this opens the door to more problems than it solves. What happens if people who are "**really** not technical at all" use such a sheet and check the box on the wrong row, or decide after the fact that they made a mistake (which is a virtual certainty)? What if they then check the box on the row that was just created in error, expecting that it will remove it (because now you'd have two unwanted rows)? My clients' skill level runs from complete novice to intermediate user; and there is usually a way to restructure the entire system to work for each.

Comment: I will also add that, in my opinion, this post asks the unpaid volunteer contributors here to do free work for you (not merely to pass along a little knowledge or to help fix part of a formula you've already written). In business, we generally can't just go somewhere and say, "I 'have no idea how' to do X. Can you do it for me for free?" Consider this forum as an advice column, not a source where anyone can receive customized, time-intensive development services at no cost. If it would take someone more than 5 or 10 minutes to do... it's real work.

Answer (score 0):

#### Add Row underneath current row

```
function addNewRowUnderneathCurrentRow() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  sh.insertRowAfter(sh.getActiveRange().getRow())
}
```

[image]

[image]